# Ruby on Rails generators are not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem.
When I'm trying to generate something via rails g/rails generate controller/model/etc I got this message as an output in my terminal.
What I am doing wrong?

```
user@vps:/var/www/dap$ rails -v
Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.
Rails 4.2.0
user@vps:/var/www/dap$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
user@vps:/var/www/dap$ ruby script/generate controller StaticPages home help about ruby: No such file or directory -- script/generate (LoadError)
user@vps:/var/www/dap$ bin/rails generate controller StaticPages home help about
Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.
^C/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client/run.rb:99:in `gets': Interrupt
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client/run.rb:99:in `verify_server_version'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client/run.rb:56:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client/run.rb:37:in `warm_run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client/run.rb:26:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:23:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.3.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /var/www/dap/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

P.S. Added ruby and rails versions, just in a case.

Comment: Have you tried same syntax `rails g controller static_pages home help about`

Comment: I've solved this issue by removing gem 'spring' form my Gemfile.
And yes, I've tried both options. Both were not working (the same output lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 4.2 requires ruby version at least 1.9.3. Prefers 2.0+

Don't use [outdated](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) version.

Also, is look like you are using system ruby. Don`t use it. Stick to [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [RVM](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm)